# Variable value doesn't change after second while loop

Tags: javascript

I have a variable `num` which I give a value. After the first while loop the value changes, but when I try to use the new value on a second while loop, the final result won't depend by the new `num`.

```js
var a = 1,
  b = 13,
  c = 0,
  p; ///6227020800   /// 48648600  ///1801800  ///1245404160  -> /5

function div(p) {
  for (var i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    if (p % i !== 0) {
      c++;
    }
  }
  if (c === 0) {
    return 'YES'
  }
  return 'NO'
}

var num = 6227020800;

while (div(num) == "YES") {
  num /= 2;
}
num = num * 2; // num === 48648600

while (div(num) == "YES") {
  num /= 3;
}

num = num * 3; // num should be ///1801800 when num === 48648600

while (div(num) == "YES") {
  num /= 5;
}

num = num * 5 // finally num should be 360360 when num === 1801800
```

Comment: You’re never using the variable `p`.

Comment: Now I see, but that should't be a problem if  it's declared and not used..

Comment: Don't use strings like `"YES"` and `"NO"` to represent truth. That's what Boolean values are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear to me what you are trying to accomplish, but it seems that after the very first run of `div()`, `c` gets sooner or later incremented, and then it will never be `0` again. Therefore, `div()` will never return `"YES"` and the following `while`-loops will never be executed.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was with the function c variable so I made three functions with 3 vars c, h, l all equals to 0 for my while loops.I don't know if it's the best method but as long as it works I'll take it ;)

Comment: Maybe you should just do `c = 0;` before each `while()` loop?

Answer (score 1):

Simplify `div` as follows:

```
function div(p) {
  for (var i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    if (p % i !== 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

This gets rid of the `c` variable which you had forgot to declare locally.

Now just change the rest of your program to handle the Boolean return from `div` instead of looking for `"YES"` or `"NO"`.